# Sublime Text 2: Error parsing plist xml: Failed to open file in file

Tags: xml, sublimetext2

This problem began I think when I tried to install package control in Sublime Text 2 and it wasn't working right so I uninstalled Sublime Text and reinstalled it. Now it fails to install completely. Here is a screen shot of the error:

[image: Error plist xml]

When I troubleshoot in Windows it says the application is not compatible. I went to the Sublime Text forum for help but I didn't see anything that matched my problem exactly. I'm kind of lost on this one.

Comment: I'd ***strongly*** recommend using [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3) instead. Despite its "beta" name, it's as solid as a rock and has been for the last 1-2 years (depending on who you ask). I've been using it pretty much exclusively since about the middle of 2013. There are too many new features to list, but suffice it to say that ST2 is EOL'd, and will have no further bug fixes or patches released. All dev work is now being done on ST3, and work has been started (architecting, at least, if not actual code-writing) on ST4.

Comment: I thought about Sublime Text 3 but I figured it wouldn't make a difference. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to try it.

Comment: It's a *huge* difference. Plus, many new and/or popular plugins are moving towards supporting ST3 only (Sublime's Python API changed in some backwards-incompatible ways), either dropping ST2 entirely, or just leaving them as-is.

Comment: I just successfully installed Sublime Text 3. Thank you, again.

Comment: No problem. If you have questions, make sure to search first (google is better than the site search), then ask if you can't find anything. The forum is also good, when it's up (it dies periodically - really irritating).